# What does the "16" refer to in "16-bit Bilevel Gray" and "Depth: 16/1-bit"

Tags: image

ImageMagick's `identify` command line tool provides information on sampled images contained in image files. I'm trying to understand what the "16" means in the context of what it reports back.

I'm pretty sure this is a monochrome image with just one bit of content and one transparency bit per pixel, so I don't understand the role the "16" plays here. Is it that the 1 represents a grey level "value" of 65535 (i.e. all white, in this case)? Or does this have something to do with the 1-bit of content channel and 1-bit of alpha/transparency channel being packed into a 16-bit word?

In non-verbose mode, it reports:

```
20140123124823096.pdf PDF 1008x612 1008x612+0+0 **16-bit Bilevel Gray** 77.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

In verbose mode, it reports the following:

```
Image: 20140123124823096.pdf
  Format: PDF (Portable Document Format)
  Mime type: application/pdf
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1008x612+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 14x8.5
  Units: Undefined
  Type: Bilevel
  Base type: Bilevel
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: Gray
  Depth: 16/1-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 1-bit
    alpha: 1-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Gray:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 65535 (1)
      mean: 60686.5 (0.926017)
      standard deviation: 17153.4 (0.261744)
      kurtosis: 8.59646
      skewness: -3.25522
    Alpha:
      min: 65535 (1)
      max: 65535 (1)
      mean: 65535 (1)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: 0
      skewness: 0
  Colors: 2
  Histogram:
     45640: (    0,    0,    0,65535) #000000000000 graya(0,1)
    571256: (65535,65535,65535,65535) #FFFFFFFFFFFF graya(255,1)
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: graya(255,1)
  Border color: graya(223,1)
  Matte color: graya(189,1)
  Transparent color: graya(0,0)
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 1008x612+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Undefined
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2014-01-23T12:41:20-08:00
    date:modify: 2014-01-23T12:41:20-08:00
    pdf:HiResBoundingBox: 1008x612+0+0
    pdf:Version: PDF-1.4 
    signature: 94e55396cd1b4dea139dcb39458ada0c904d80810722d7c03a62691d710755ab
  Artifacts:
    filename: 20140123124823096.pdf
    verbose: true
  Tainted: True
  Filesize: 53.1KB
  Number pixels: 617K
  Pixels per second: 15.42MB
  User time: 0.040u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.039
  Version: ImageMagick 6.8.7-3 2013-11-20 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

**Update:** It turns out that the information that ImageMagick's tool is reporting is not actually the information about the image in the PDF file, but apparently the information about the image after it's gone through some kind of internal transformation! I looked at the PDF file in a text editor and can see that it's unambiguously a 1-bit-per-pixel monochrome image at 200 dpi (legal size), rather than the 72 dpi image with an alpha channel that ImageMagick was reporting. All that said, I'm still curious as to what the 16 means even in ImageMagick's artificial world.

Here's a description of the image as it actually exists in the PDF:

```
<</Type/XObject
/Subtype/Image
/Width 2800
/Height 1700
/BitsPerComponent 1
/ColorSpace/DeviceGray
/Filter /CCITTFaxDecode
/DecodeParms <</Columns 2800 /Rows 1700>>
/Length 142719
>>
```

Comment: Strange format indeed. Could the confusion have to do with the fact that pdf is actually a vector format, not a raster format?

Comment: No, it's clearly a sampled image, per the question update.